# how to get active tab highlighted in mat-tab?

Tags: html, css, angular-material, angular8

I am using angular material for angular development.

**HTML Component**

```
<mat-tab-group headerPosition="above" [selectedIndex]="1">
    <mat-tab label="Home" routerLinkActive="active-link"> <app-homer></app-home></mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Orders" routerLinkActive="active-link"> <app-order></app-order> </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Contact Us" routerLinkActive="active-link"> <app-contact></app-contact> </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Profile" routerLinkActive="active-link"> <app-profile></app-profile></mat-tab>
  </mat-tab-group>
```

**CSS**

```
.mat-tab-label{
    margin-top: 20px;
    border: 2px solid black; 
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    width: 10vw;
    height: 4vh !important;
    background-color: black;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    opacity: 1;
    color: yellow;
}
```

I have customized default tab which comes in white color by giving specific color and border as shown in the css.
When I load the page I am getting selected component but the tab is not active and looks like disabled. But If I click I can see the difference , the given highlighted color shows when I click it. Is there any way to make the tab look active on load.

in mat-tab-link routerLinkActive="active-link" was there but no such feature in mat-tab ?

I decided to go with mat-tag-group and mat-tab because of the animated screen loading feature.

[stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-whmn9b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: why can't you use localstorage to store the current active tab, coz as page reloads it erase all temporary data which made on page, check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62595116/navbar-active-option-does-not-remain-active-after-loading-page/62595475#62595475

Comment: can you please make this changes in my example code once and then share it with me?, my question is on load it should select a particular tab. It selects the tab but it is not looks like it is selected. Please check the given example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay one of the easiest solution is to set `ViewEncapsulation` to `None`.

component file:

```
import {Component, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  ....
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

your component css file:

```
.mat-tab-label{
    margin-top: 20px;
    border: 2px solid black; 
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    width: 10vw;
    height: 4vh !important;
    background-color: black;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    opacity: 1;
    color: yellow;
}

/* Styles for the active tab label */

// change any styles you want for active tab
.mat-tab-label.mat-tab-label-active {
    background-color: white;
}
```

your html file:

```
<mat-tab-group headerPosition="above"> // if you want specific tab then use [selectedIndex]="INDEX_OF_TAB"
    <mat-tab label="Home"></mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Orders"></mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Contact Us"></mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Profile"></mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

ref: check also [ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation)

Comment: could you please try your solution in this. In the existing page when I click I am getting tab activated , same effect I need while loading the page. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-whmn9b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: here you go https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zvram9

Comment: Thank you. I marked it as answer. For me it worked when I added opacity 2 for .mat-tab-label.mat-tab-label-active. Not sure what is the logic behind that.

Answer (score 1):

as I answered in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62595116/navbar-active-option-does-not-remain-active-after-loading-page/62595475#62595475) the browser won't keep the temporary data after the refresh, it erases all the previously done stuff, to overcome this we can use local storage mechanism, Try this local storage code this may help you,

storing to local storage

```
handleMatTabChange(event: MatTabChangeEvent) {
  localStorage.setItem('curentab', event.index);
}
```

getting back on page load:

```
ngOnInit() {
  let index = localStorage.getItem('curentab');
  this.tabGroup.selectedIndex = index; 
}
```

hope this will give you some idea,

Comment: can you please make this changes in my example code once and then share it with me?, my question is on load it should select a particular tab. It selects the tab but it is not looks like it is selected. Please check the given example